# Handling n text elements in a zend form

Tags: arrays, loops, zend-form

I have an order form that extends Zend_form:

```
class Form_Order extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);

        ...
```

Each order can have any number of products. What's the best way to pass in a list of products to repopulate the form? Just add a "values = array()" after "options"?

Bonus! How do I validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Or you can add setter method `$form->setProducts($products)`

Comment: ah, and loop thru, adding elements. Got it. Thanks!